# grid.js table not rendering html into table

Tags: html-table, grid.js

I try render html to table, I see output correct but without formatting / rendering html code.

grid.js

```
<script>
$("#tableGrid2").Grid({
    className: {
        table: 'table table-sm table-hover table-striped mb-0'
    },
    pagination: {
        limit: 20,
        summary: true,
        server: {
            url: (prev, page, limit) => `${prev}?limit=${limit}&offset=${page * limit}`
        }
    },
    server: {
        url: `<?= site_url('DashboardController/getVendorSales') ?>`,
        then: data => data.data.map(product => [
            "<div style='padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;'>" +
                "<center>hello!</center>" +
            "</div>",
            product.id,
            product.order_number,
            product.price_total,
            // Add more properties as needed
        ]),
        total: data => data.total // Use total directly here
    }
});

 
</script>
```

this part of code I see pure html in table:

```
"<div style='padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;'>" +
                "<center>hello!</center>" +
            "</div>",
```

Can anyone help me? I try  read documentation but I cannot resolve this.

Comment: as I said grid.js

Comment: grid.js table not rendering html into table